# Angular Editor rich text kolkov library font family issue

Tags: angular, rich-text-editor, font-family, richtext, kolkov-editor

i'm using Angular Editor rich text for editing text styling... i have an issue with changing th font family, it's always disabled to select a choice from the list, the selected one is the as defaultFontName.

this is the configuration

```
config: AngularEditorConfig = {
editable: true,
spellcheck: true,
height: '10rem',
minHeight: '5rem',
translate: 'no',
placeholder: 'Enter text here ....',
defaultFontName: 'Comic Sans MS',
defaultFontSize:'3',
defaultParagraphSeparator: 'p',
fonts: [
    {class: 'arial', name: 'Arial'},
    {class: 'times-new-roman', name: 'Times New Roman'},
    {class: 'calibri', name: 'Calibri'},
    {class: 'comic-sans-ms', name: 'Comic Sans MS'}
  ],
customClasses: [
  {
    name: 'Quote',
    class: 'quoteClass',
  },
  {
    name: 'Title Heading',
    class: 'titleHead',
    tag: 'h1',
  },
],
sanitize: false,
toolbarHiddenButtons:[
    ['insertImage'],
    ['insertVideo'],
    ['backgroundColor','customClasses'],
    ['insertOrderedList', 'insertUnorderedList'],
    ['link', 'unlink','toggleEditorMode']
]
```

anyone has any idea why is it always disabled and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

have to add one of the following in your `angular.json`,

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.gif",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/assets/",
                "output": "./assets/fonts/"
              }
            ],

   "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "./node_modules/@kolkov/angular-editor/assets/",
                "output": "./assets/fonts/"
              }
            ],
```

Comment: it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in my same component I had 2 different editors , I removed other editor and I was able to select Font-Family.

Answer (score 0):

In this case Event you mapped in angular-editor is mouseup
like (mouseup)="onPointerDown()" which typically corresponds to a mouse button being released
so change mouseup to (click)="onPointerDown()"

this will solve the issue